# how to install server worker correctly in vue

Tags: vue.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: '/' })
          .then(function(registration) {
            // Успешная регистрация
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful');
          }, function(err) {
            // При регистрации произошла ошибка
            console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
          });
      });
     }
  </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br6Fm.png)

```
ServiceWorker registration failed:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://localhost:8080/') with script ('https://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
```

When installing server workera gives an error, I can't understand what is wrong?

Comment: please paste the code rather than image. otherwise you might get a downvote.